# shared clipboard (copy-paste) not working VirtualBox 7.0 and Ubuntu Server 20.04.5 focal

Tags: virtualbox, clipboard

I am unable to copy and paste between Ubuntu Server 20.04 running inside VirtualBox 7.0.4 and my Mac OSX host 11.7.1. How can I make it work?

In order to paste I'm trying:

- copy some text on my Mac
- click inside my Ubuntu machine
- press cmd+v, or ctrl+v, and nothing happens

What I've tried so far

- Devices > Shared Clipboard > set to Bidirectional
- Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD Image ...

  - this doesn't appear to have any effect

So I tried to run it manually:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/cdrom
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
# install build-essential otherwise I get errors when installing guest additions
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install build-essential
sudo /mnt/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

it produces a couple errors, but otherwise appears to install

```
/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-7.0.4/bin/VBoxClient: error while loading shared libraries: libXt.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

```
VirtualBoxGuestAdditions: Starting.
...
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the modules for kernel 5.4.0-132-generic.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-132-generic
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Running kernel modules will not be replaced until the system is restarted
```

Then I shut down and start up my virtual machine.

But I'm still not able to paste.

Next I tried installing these packages which are recommended in other answers:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) dkms
```

And then re-running

```
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
sudo /mnt/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

And then shutting down and starting up the VM. I'm still not able to paste.

Finally, I tried

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils
```

shut down and started up my machine, but it's still not working.

What else can I try?

Comment: I have yet to get the Virtualbox Extension Pack on VB7 to actually load and work correctly.  All of the VB systems I have it causes a reboot when trying to insert the Extension Pack for loading.  I went and deleted it, and redownloaded it, but nothing I did could fix it.  So, I went back to VB 6.1 until they can fix the VB Extensions Pack.

Comment: I am trying my steps above with VirtualBox 6.1 and still having the same problem

Comment: How are you trying to paste?  Ctrl+V doesn't work through VB.  I have only been able to get it to work through right-click for both copy from the host and to paste into the client within VB.

Comment: I was trying various keyboard paste shortcuts. I'm trying the mouse now but right clicking doesn't do anything in the virtual machine. I'm guessing because it's Ubuntu Server which only has a command line and no GUI or mouse integration

Comment: Yeah, that can do it.  You can open a ssh session to it, and you should be able to paste into a ssh session.